# $|A\cap C|$ and $|B\cap C|$ are both even $\Rightarrow$ $|(A\bigtriangleup B)\cap C|$ is even?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two infinite sets such that $|A\cap C|$ and $|B\cap C|$ are both even for set $C$. Does it imply that $|(A\bigtriangleup B)\cap C|$ is even?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true.

Consider size of intersection of $C$ with $A-B, A \cap B, B-A$, say $x,y,z$.

We have that $x+y$ is even and $y+z$ is even, and thus $x+2y+z$ is even, $\implies x+z$ is even, which is what you want.